# Algorithm Development for a Mentoring Event

Tags: algorithm

I am attempting to create an algorithm that pairs mentees with a different group of 1-4 mentors in each "round" of mentoring.

The algorithm would accept 3 inputs:

- The number of mentees - an integer between 1 and 35
- The number of mentors - Always greater than or equal to the number of mentees, but never greater than 35
- The number of rounds of mentoring to perform

Given these three inputs, the algorithm would match each mentee with 1-4 mentors, with the following restrictions:

- If it is possible to do so with the given inputs, a mentee must never be paired with the same mentor more than once
- If it is possible to do so with the given inputs, a mentor must never be in the same group of mentors as another mentor more than once

Note: The algorithm does NOT have to assign mentors to mentees randomly. The code can give the same output each time it is run with the same set of inputs.

Here is an example of the output of a successful algorithm with 2 rounds, 4 mentees, and 11 mentors:

`|                   Round
 | Mentee   |    1   |    2    |
 |    1     | 1, 2, 3| 4, 7, 10|
 |    2     | 4, 5, 6| 1, 8, 11|
 |    3     | 7, 8, 9| 2, 5    |
 |    4     |10, 11  | 3, 6, 9 |`

Please let me know if you have any questions, or if what I am asking for is in fact impossible. Thank you very much for your time and assistance, and have a great day.

Sincerely,
Tyrovar

Comment: Wait. You want us just to code this for you? That's not how this site works buddy.

Comment: Agreed, please review: [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If you already have a successful algorithm why are you asking us for one ?

Comment: Jeremy W, I've looked over your link, and I don't see where my question would be invalid. I am asking for help developing a high-level algorithm to solve the problem. I can fill in the details on my own, I just need help figuring out where to start. High Performance Mark, the output I have posted is just that - output. Think of it as a test case for what the algorithm should output.

Comment: I used brute force to come up with the test case. If I were to do that for the program itself, I would need to test a maximum of 35^35 cases per round, or a maximum of 1.10e54 cases per round. Would backtracking be an option to deal with a problem like this?

Comment: Your usage of mentors and mentees seem inconsistent to me, and I find it highly confusing. Perhaps better replace with teachers and students. Usually the number of mentors (teachers) are less than the number of mentees (students).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting problem!

It's unlikely that it has a fast solution, unfortunately, because it's related to some long-standing combinatorial problems that don't have efficient constructive solutions I'm aware of.

You can think of the problem in two parts: (1) deciding the *groups of mentors* for each round, and then (2) *pairing* these groups with mentees.

Call `n` the number of mentors and `m <= n` the number of mentees. And assume `m` evenly divides `n`. (If not, you could just add `m - (n mod m)` "fake" mentors, i.e. empty chairs.)

Then just the first part (1) to figure out the groups of mentors in each round, is equivalent (with sufficiently many rounds) to finding a `S(2, n/m, n)` [Steiner Triple System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steiner_system). There has been a good deal of research on these combinatorial objects, and some algorithms published, but to my knowledge none of them will be fast or even polynomial-time.

However, for reasonable parameter sizes, you could hope to generate the groups of mentors with a *greedy algorithm* approach: For each mentor, keep track (in a `set` data structure) of which other mentors that mentor has been in groups with already. For each round, start making groups of mentors that haven't been in groups with each other yet, and then add those group members to each list. If this fails, however, you may have to resort to a brute-force approach to find the groups.

Once you have the groups of mentors, pairing them with the mentees in each round becomes an instance of the [bipartite perfect matching problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#In_unweighted_bipartite_graphs), to which there are a few reasonably efficient solutions, including the [Hopcroft-Karp algorithm](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/0202019). Again, you would want to keep track of which mentors each mentee has seen, and update these in each round.

So in general, the approach I would suggest is:

1. Create a `set` of mentors for every mentor and for every mentee, initially empty.
2. *Greedily* select `m/n` groups of `n` mentors each that have not been in the same group before. If you get "stuck", resort to a *brute-force* search over all possible groupings until you find a suitable one.
3. Create a bipartite graph, with one vertex for each mentee, one vertex for each *group* of mentors in the current round, and an edge between them if none of the mentors in the group has seen that mentee yet.
4. Find a maximum matching in that graph - this is the pairings of mentors to mentees for the current round.
5. Repeat Steps 2-4 for the remaining rounds.

You might also want to look at the [Kirkman's Schoolgirl's Problem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KirkmansSchoolgirlProblem.html), which is closely related to what you are asking and a good, simple illustration of why it's difficult in general to solve.

Comment: This looks promising. Adding in "empty" mentors is a good move to ensure that I'm creating equal sets, and if I run into a situation where a mentee has no "real" mentors, I can always swap the groups around after the fact to ensure everyone has at least one "real" mentor. I think that I'm going to try this and see how it goes. Thank you very much for your help.